# MySql, find in paragraphs with regex

Tags: mysql, regex

sorry for my English.
I’m trying to find text by this query with regexp:

```
SELECT * FROM p_posts  where Text REGEXP '[[:<:]]Liberty[[:>:]]'and Text REGEXP '[[:<:]]Rig.*[[:>:]]'and Text REGEXP '[[:<:]]7[[:>:]]'and Text REGEXP '[[:<:]]22[[:>:]]'
```

All works fine. But now I need to find records, where these words are in one paragraph. For example, if word Liberty and number 22 aren’t in one paragraph, then this record not valid.
Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This will be tricky to do with MySQL regex because you have neither lookarounds nor non-greedy  matches.

I would suggest that you split the string according to the paragraph delimeters and then search for the matches in the paragraph strings. An example split function that was taken from **[here](http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/)**:

```
CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STR(
  x VARCHAR(255),
  delim VARCHAR(12),
  pos INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
       LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
       delim, '');
```